# Could not create Java Virtual Machine in VS 2015 TACO tools

Tags: cordova, android-emulator, visual-studio-cordova

While i am using the latest Cordova tools in Visual Studio 2015 v1.0.0. I am getting this error when i am trying to use Visual Studion Emulator 5" KitKat (4.4). I am using Windows 10 on my machine.

[image]

Any thoughts how to fix this.

Answer (score 4):

I found the fix for this error, follow these steps:

1) Close Visual Studio.

2) Open the Control Panel.

3) Go to System and Security.

4) Go to System.

5) Go to Advanced systems settings.

6) Go to Environment Variables... (on the Advanced tab).

7) Under System Variables, click New...

8) Set the following:

Variable Name: _JAVA_OPTIONS

Variable Value: -Xmx512M

9) Click Apply and OK to close the dialog.

10) Sign out from your machine, This is an important step.

11) Sign in again,m re-open Visual Studio

12) Build you project!

Enjoy!

Comment: Note that you may need to bump up the heap to 1024 (-Xmx1024M) or higher if you have a significant number of plugins.  If you need to exceed 1024M, you should install and configure a 64-bit version of the JDK as the 32-bit version maxes out around 1 gig of heap.

Comment: i had a same error earlier, from your comment i felt like i don't have enough memory. so i closed the browser and few other programs and it worked fine